# Can't update system?

Tags: 20.04, updates, system, lts, 20.10

I get a lot of notifications of a system update, when I'm trying to update it, it asks to restart the computer, and then nothing happens just keep asking to restart & update
[image: Like this pic]

Comment: Please add `pkcon refresh` and `pkcon get-updates` to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The Software app sometimes gets false positives in the Updates tab for packages that have already been updated automatically, but the Software app hasn't been refreshed to know about it yet. If you clicked the green *Restart & Update* button and nothing happened, then ignore the update button and the update notification will go away by itself. This unexpected behavior in the Software app does not have any effect on updating software from the terminal which still functions properly in the usual way.

Comment: Check the Updates tab in the Software app again. Maybe the green button went away by itself already,